# Not able to use tkprof utility

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-performance

Hi I have below trc file. When i am using tkprof it is giving error.

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -ltr ac1dv224_ora_7223_1509935.trc
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 4388454 Dec  4 03:14 ac1dv224_ora_7223_1509935.trc
-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$ tkprof ac1dv224_ora_7223_1509935.trc  ac1dv224_ora_7223_1509935.out

TKPROF: Release 10.1.0.5.0 - Production on Fri Dec 4 03:14:49 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


could not open output file ac1dv224_ora_7223_1509935.out
```

Could you please help me to do that. I am new in database.

I also tried below command, still getting same error.

```
-bash-4.1$ tkprof ac1dv224_ora_6811.trc translated.txt explain=apps/apps table=sys.plan_table sys=no waits=yes
```

Comment: Which user are you executing 'tkprof' as? -> type 'whoami'. Try create a file in folder -> 'touch _myfile'

Comment: it is coming as devuser.      -bash-4.1$ whoami
devuser

Comment: Are you able to create file in folder? -> 'touch _myfile'

Comment: you got it correctly. I am not able to create file in unix. Thanks Bjarte